# Sum of a measure per date range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following Table Visualization.

[image]

I'd like the table to look like the following.  Column C should be averaging the range of Column B.
For example:

```
C2 = AVERAGE(B2:B2)
C3 = AVERAGE(B2:B3)
C4 = AVERAGE(B2:B4)
```

and so on.

[image]

The Year-Month column is from my MonthTable.  The schema is as follows,

[image]

And the Sum measure DAX is as follows,

[image]

For the CumulativeSum measure, I have tried the following.

```
CumulativeSum = 
CALCULATE(
[Sum],FILTER(AppendedTables,AppendedTables[Year-Month] <= MAX(AppendedTables[Year-Month]))
)
```

I'm guessing the issue is my `CALCULATE([SUM])` area.  I wanted to wrap `[SUM]` in a `SUM()` method, but that doesn't work.  It gives the error "The SUM function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1".

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to produce your desired results by creating a calculated column using the following code:

```
CumSum = 
VAR CntRow =
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Sheet1, [Year-Month] >= EARLIER ( [Year-Month] ) ) )
VAR CumSum =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Sum] ),
        FILTER ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Year-Month] >= EARLIER ( Sheet1[Year-Month] ) )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( CumSum, CntRow )
```

[image]

Hope this helps!!